# dispatch thunk return to component

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to pass the response of a dispatched function back to my component code. I get an signed request from my backend then upload the file from my component.

my component code here get's an S3 signature from my backend to upload a file

```
handleSubmitClick = async () => {
        if (this.state.name){
            let newFile = {
        filename: this.state.name,
        filetype: this.state.media.type,
            }
            this.props.signS3(newFile.filename, newFile.filetype)
                .then( res => console.log('NO RESPONSE', res))

            this.handleCloseClick();

        } else {
            this.setState({ inputError: true });
        }
  }
```

i get signS3 from mapdispatchtoprops

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
        handleCancelClick() {
            dispatch(openAttachAssetModal(false));
        },
        signS3(filename, filetype) {
            dispatch(signS3(filename, filetype));
        }
  }
}
```

It runs my mutation

```
export function signS3(filename, filetype) {
  return function thunk(dispatch) {
    const client = ApolloClient();
    return client.mutate({
      variables: { filename, filetype },
      mutation: gql`
        mutation signS3($filename: String!, $filetype: String!){
          signS3(input: {
            filename: $filename
            filetype: $filetype
          }) {
            signedRequest
            url
          }
        }
      `
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response
    })
  }
}
```

except I don't get a response returned...

Answer (score 1):

In `mapDispatchToProps` you have to return what you're dispatching (in this case a promise) in `signS3` otherwise the value will be undefined.

```
// ...
signS3(filename, filetype) {
    return dispatch(signS3(filename, filetype));
}
```